How to Align KDE Plots to the Edges of a Scatterplot in React with TypeScript and D3.js
I am working on creating a component that includes scatterplots for multiple datasets and KDE (Kernel Density Estimation) plots for the x and y-coordinates of those datasets, in React with TypeScript using D3.js.
So far, I have successfully implemented the KDE plot and the scatter plot. However, I am having trouble aligning the KDE plots to the right and top edges of my scatterplot, similar to how scatterhist produces output in MATLAB.
I tried using the .attr("transform", translate(${width},${0})) and other such combinations but I have not been able to place it within the svg canvas.
const Scatterplot: React.FC<{
  width: number;
  height: number;
  datasets: { x: number; y: number }[][];
  labels: string[];
  plotType: "ellipse" | "rectangle";
  p?: number;
  bandwidth?: number;
}> = ({
  width,
  height,
  datasets,
  labels,
  plotType,
  p = 0.95,
  bandwidth = 4,
}) => {
  const svgRef = useRef<SVGSVGElement | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const svgElement = svgRef.current;
    if (!svgElement) return;

    const svg = d3.select(svgElement);
    svg.selectAll("*").remove();
    svg.style("background-color", "white");
    const boundsWidth = width - MARGIN.right - MARGIN.left;
    const boundsHeight = height - MARGIN.top - MARGIN.bottom;
    const g = svg
      .attr("width", width + MARGIN.left + MARGIN.right)
      .attr("height", height + MARGIN.top + MARGIN.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", `translate(${MARGIN.left},${MARGIN.top})`);

    const colors = d3.schemeCategory10;

    const mu: [number, number][] = datasets.map((dataset) =>
      calculateMean(dataset)
    );

    const Sigma = datasets.map((dataset, index) =>
      calculateCovarianceMatrix(dataset, mu[index])
    );

    const maxX = d3.max(datasets.flat(), (d) => d.x) || 10;
    const maxY = d3.max(datasets.flat(), (d) => d.y) || 10;
    const minX = d3.min(datasets.flat(), (d) => d.x) || 0;
    const minY = d3.min(datasets.flat(), (d) => d.y) || 0;

    const bufferX = 3;
    const bufferY = 3;
    const xScale = d3
      .scaleLinear()
      .domain([minX - bufferX, maxX + bufferX])
      .range([0, width]);

    const yScale = d3
      .scaleLinear()
      .domain([minY - bufferY, maxY + bufferY])
      .range([height, 0]);

    const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale);
    const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale);

    g.append("g")
      .attr("transform", `translate(0,${height})`)
      .call(xAxis)
      .call((g) => g.selectAll(".domain, .tick line").attr("stroke", "#000"))
      .call((g) => g.selectAll(".tick text").attr("fill", "#000"))
      .append("text")
      .attr("class", "x-axis-label")
      .attr("fill", "#000")
      .attr("x", width / 2)
      .attr("y", MARGIN.bottom - 1)
      .attr("dy", "1em")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle");

    g.append("g")
      .call(yAxis)
      .call((g) => g.selectAll(".domain, .tick line").attr("stroke", "#000"))
      .call((g) => g.selectAll(".tick text").attr("fill", "#000"))
      .append("text")
      .attr("class", "y-axis-label")
      .attr("fill", "#000")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("x", -height / 2)
      .attr("y", -MARGIN.left + 10)
      .attr("dy", "1em")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle");

    datasets.forEach((data, i) => {
      // console.log(data);
      const color = colors[i % colors.length];

      g.selectAll(`.dot${i}`)
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("class", `dot${i}`)
        .attr("cx", (d) => xScale(d.x))
        .attr("cy", (d) => yScale(d.y))
        .attr("stroke", color)
        .attr("stroke-opacity", 1)
        .attr("stroke-width", 1)
        .attr("r", 2.5)
        .attr("fill", color)
        .attr("fill-opacity", 0.5);

      const legend = g
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "legend")
        .attr("transform", `translate(${width - MARGIN.right},${i * 20})`);

      legend
        .append("rect")
        .attr("x", MARGIN.right)
        .attr("y", MARGIN.top -10)
        .attr("width", 18)
        .attr("height", 18)
        .style("fill", color);

      legend
        .append("text")
        .attr("x", MARGIN.right -10)
        .attr("y", MARGIN.top)
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .text(labels[i]);

      if (plotType === "rectangle") {
        [2, 3].forEach((sdMultiplier) => {
          const rectData = calculateConfidenceRectangle(
            mu[i],
            Sigma[i],
            sdMultiplier
          );
          const rectX = xScale(rectData.x);
          const rectY = yScale(rectData.y + rectData.height); 
          const rectWidth =
            xScale(rectData.x + rectData.width) - xScale(rectData.x);
          const rectHeight =
            yScale(rectData.y) - yScale(rectData.y + rectData.height);

          g.append("rect")
            .attr("x", rectX)
            .attr("y", rectY)
            .attr("width", rectWidth)
            .attr("height", rectHeight)
            .style("fill", "none")
            .style("stroke", color)
            .style("stroke-width", 1.5)
            .style("stroke-dasharray", sdMultiplier === 3 ? "4 2" : "none");
        });
      } else if (plotType === "ellipse") {
        [0.95, 0.99].forEach((confidence, j) => {
          const ellipseData = plotErrorEllipse(mu[i], Sigma[i], confidence);

          const cx = xScale(ellipseData.cx);
          const cy = yScale(ellipseData.cy);
          const rx = xScale(mu[i][0] + ellipseData.rx) - xScale(mu[i][0]);
          const ry = yScale(mu[i][1]) - yScale(mu[i][1] + ellipseData.ry);

          g.append("ellipse")
            .attr("cx", cx)
            .attr("cy", cy)
            .attr("rx", Math.abs(rx))
            .attr("ry", Math.abs(ry))
            .attr("transform", `rotate(${ellipseData.angle}, ${cx}, ${cy})`)
            .style("fill", "none")
            .style("stroke", color)
            .style("stroke-width", 1.5)
            .style("stroke-dasharray", j === 1 ? "4 2" : "none");
        });
      }
      const kdeX = kernelDensityEstimator(
        epanechnikovKernel(bandwidth),
        xScale.ticks(100)
      );
      const kdeY = kernelDensityEstimator(
        epanechnikovKernel(bandwidth),
        yScale.ticks(100)
      );
      const kdeDataX = kdeX(data.map((d) => d.x));
      const lineX = d3
        .line()
        .x((d) => xScale(d[0]))
        .y((d) => yScale(d[1]))
        .curve(d3.curveBasis);
      g.append("path")
        .datum(kdeDataX)
        .attr("class", "kde-x")
        .attr("d", lineX)
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .attr("stroke", color)
        .attr("stroke-width", 1);

      const kdeDataY = kdeY(data.map((d) => d.y));
      const lineY = d3
        .line()
        .x((d) => xScale(d[1]))
        .y((d) => yScale(d[0]))
        .curve(d3.curveBasis);

      g.append("path")
        .datum(kdeDataY)
        .attr("class", "kde-y")
        .attr("d", lineY)
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .attr("stroke", color)
        .attr("stroke-width", 1);
    });
  }, [width, height, datasets, labels, plotType, p, bandwidth]);

  return (
    <div>
      <svg ref={svgRef}></svg>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Scatterplot;


Current output:

Desired output:


Going to be very hard to give you a definitive answer given the small amount of non-reproducible code you show...  But I'd approach the problem by placing the two KDE lines in their own g element and then translating each of those into the right or top margins respectively.

@Mark Your suggestion worked, I created 2 elements one for each plot. Thank you so much!
